# Help, frustrated: Placing dialog relative to trigger using just jQuery UI dialog + position

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog, position

Is it possible to place a jQuery UI-based dialog relative to its trigger link using just jQuery UI dialog and position scripts (and not some other plugin or method)? There's no viable demos that I can find, and the Jensbits method referenced here frequently seems to fall apart in IE8, which I have to support.

A coding colleague had gotten me this far in the javascript included below, but the commented-out portion beginning "var offset" only offsets the *content* within the dialog, and not the dialog itself, and doesn't seem to help in positioning the dialog just underneath the button. As shown, the dialog loads default page center.

I'd really appreciate any assistance with this. Thank you! --cg

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<!-- YUI3 reset only: -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?3.3.0/build/cssreset/reset-min.css">

<!-- JQuery CDN -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- JQuery UI CDN -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- JQuery UI scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>

<style media="screen" type="text/css">
<!--
/* styles for demo purposes only, do not copy */
body{width:97%;margin:0 1.5%;font:13px/1.231 'Arial Unicode MS',Arial,Verdana,sans-serif !important}
strong{font-weight:bold}
a{color:#034ea2}
a:hover{color:#ff7600}
p{margin:0 0 1em}
#page{min-width:780px;max-width:1260px;margin:12px auto}
/* end demo styles */

/* dialog base */
.dialog.ui-dialog{overflow:hidden;border:1px solid #a2aaaf;-moz-box-shadow:0px 1px 3px #7c888f;-webkit-box-shadow:0px 1px 3px #7c888f;box-shadow:0px 1px 3px #a2aaaf;background:#ffffff}
.dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar{margin-bottom:6px;padding:4px 6px;border-bottom:1px solid #dadddf;background:#eceeef;font-size:11px;color:#455560}
.dialog .ui-dialog-title-dialog{float:left}
.dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close
{float:right;width:17px;height:17px;position:relative;top:-1px;text-indent:-9999px;background:orange}
.dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close:hover{background-position:0 -30px}
.dialog .ui-dialog-content{padding:4px 10px 8px}

-->
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="page">

    <!-- dialog trigger -->
    <button id="opendialog01">Open dialog</button>

</div>

<!-- dialog -->
<div class="dialog" id="dialog01" title="Test dialog">

    <p>[dialog content]</p>

</div>

<!-- initialize dialog -->
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$.fx.speeds._default = 100;

$(function() {

    $(".dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: "blind",
        hide: "blind",
        width: 400,
        modal: false,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        dialogClass: "dialog"
    });

    var showDialog = function (e, $trigger, $dialog) {
        e.preventDefault();
          /*
          var offset = $trigger.offset();
          $dialog.position({
            of: $trigger,
            my: "left top",
            at: "left bottom"
          });
          */
          $dialog.dialog("open");
        return false;
     };

    $("#opendialog01").click(function(e) {
        return showDialog( e, $(this), $("#dialog01") );
    });

});
-->
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you embed the UI js twice? The minified package from the CDN already contains core, position, dialog etc.

Answer (score 2):

Got help on this offline from a fellow designer. Solution for positioning a jQuery-based dialog relative to a link/button using jQuery position (my, at, of method at http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Position) is below. Works in major browsers including IE back to v7.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<!-- YUI3 reset only: -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?3.3.0/build/cssreset/reset-min.css">

<!-- JQuery CDN -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- JQuery UI CDN -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<style media="screen" type="text/css">
<!--
body{width:97%;margin:0 1.5%;font:13px/1.231 'Arial Unicode MS',Arial,Verdana,sans-serif}
#page{min-width:780px;max-width:1260px;margin:12px auto}

/* dialog base */
.dialog.ui-dialog{overflow:hidden;border:1px solid #a2aaaf;-moz-box-shadow:0px 1px 3px #7c888f;-webkit-box-shadow:0px 1px 3px #7c888f;box-shadow:0px 1px 3px #a2aaaf;background:#ffffff}
.dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar{margin-bottom:6px;padding:4px 6px;border-bottom:1px solid #dadddf;background:#eceeef;font-size:11px;color:#455560}
.dialog .ui-dialog-title-dialog{float:left}
.dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close
{float:right;width:17px;height:17px;position:relative;top:-1px;text-indent:-9999px;background:orange/* color for illo purposes only */ url('[image]') 0 0 no-repeat}
.dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close:hover{background-position:0 -30px}
.dialog .ui-dialog-content{padding:4px 10px 8px}

-->
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="page">

    <!-- dialog trigger -->
    <button id="opendialog01">Open dialog</button>

</div>

<!-- dialog -->
<div class="dialog" id="dialog01" title="Test dialog">

    <p>[dialog content]</p>

</div>

<!-- initialize dialog -->
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$.fx.speeds._default = 100;

$(function() {

    $(".dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: "blind",
        hide: "blind",
        width: 400,
        modal: false,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        dialogClass: "dialog"
    });

    function showDialog (e, $trigger, $dialog) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $dialog.dialog("option", "position", {
            my: "left top",
            at: "left bottom",
            of: $trigger
        });
        $dialog.dialog("open");
    };

    $("#opendialog01").click(function(e) {
        return showDialog (e, $(this), $("#dialog01") );
    });

});
-->
</script>

</body>
</html>
```